# I have this error when add column to database dbml file linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, controller

This this my dbml file  in the asp.net mvc core 5
[image]

When i try to create a new entity for my modified table and then drag/cut the new property from the new entity to my old one , I have this error in the controller

'dbQLBansachDataContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Add constructor without parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Visual Studio doesnt not include in the file (inside the DBML ...___designer.cs > dbQLBansachDataContext.designer.cs) the empty constructor. You need to add it.

public dbQLBansachDataContext() :

```
    base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
  {
      OnCreated();
  }
```